# How to set ComboBox editor event handler

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm trying to add a key event handler to an editable ComboBox in a simple JavaFX application. Since the Scene Builder doesn't provide access to the TextField in the ComboBox, I have to add the event handler in code.

Here is my attempt to add the handler.

### Main class

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox combo;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();

        Controller c = loader.getController();
        combo.getEditor().setOnKeyTyped(c::handleComboKeyPress);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

### Controller class

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private ComboBox combo;

    public void handleComboKeyPress(KeyEvent ke)
    {
        System.out.print("key press. ");  // debugging
        String query = combo.getEditor().getText();
        System.out.println(query);   // debugging
    }
}
```

### FXML (sample.fxml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="400.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <ComboBox fx:id="combo" editable="true" layoutX="75.0" layoutY="34.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="City, State" visibleRowCount="5" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

This crashes with a null pointer exception on the last line of the start method. The problem is `combo` doesn't have a value yet because (I assume) the FXML loader runs in a separate thread and isn't finished by the time my code tries to call getEditor.

What is a more appropriate way to set the event handler?

Edit: added complete source code

Comment: Were are you defining `combo` and where it is initialized?

Comment: Also, if you actually have an object for `combo`, did you check if it does return an object when you do `getEditor()`?

Comment: `combo` is the fx:id for the ComboBox in the FXML file. The value of `combo` is null; the call to getEditor is throwing the exception.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Yeah. I am not sure that the annotation `@FXML` its actually doing the dependency injection you think its doing. An easy way to check this is by doing `if (null == combo)`; plus, you can try `if(null == combo.getEditor())` to ensure that you do get an editor.

Comment: You're probably using the wrong controller instance. You also appear to be using your `Application` class as a controller which is typically considered bad practice. That said, providing a [mcve] will allow us to better help you.

Comment: Added complete source code.

Comment: As Slaw suggested Main#combo is not the same as Controller#combo, Main#combo is probably null when you're attempting to set it.  You need to setup a delegate on your sample.Controller to pass through to the Controller#combo.getEditor() or something along those lines.

Comment: looks like @kendavidson nails it :-)

Comment: Yes, he did. I'm new to JavaFX, so I'm still unclear on how all the pieces fit together. I thought that fx:ids were singletons and that annotating a variable with `@FXML` gives you a reference to the global object, no matter what scope the variable is declared in. This is probably worthy of a separate SO question: how does the annotation "know" which variables to bind to the instance defined by the FXML file and which ones to leave dangling?

Comment: @barrybrown it comes from your loader. You're loading sample.fxml which has the fx:controller set. That is the controller that gets injected and initialized.

Comment: The `FXMLLoader` is aware of the `Class` of your controller; in your case, from the fully qualified name specified by `fx:controller`. When you load the FXML file it creates an instance of the controller for you. Later, the `FXMLLoader` obtains the `Field`s of the `Class` and searches them for ones whose names match the `fx:id`s. When a match is found it attempts to reflectively set the `Field` to the object created from the FXML element. _This injection only happens with the controller **instance** — the `FXMLLoader` is not aware of every object instance in your application_.

Comment: Note the `@FXML` annotation is only necessary when the field or method is non-public. The annotation is basically just telling the `FXMLLoader` it's okay to try and access the non-public member. Also, you hypothesized your issue was related to threads—it is not. Everything the `FXMLLoader` does happens on the thread that called `load`. In other words, the code you've shown is sequential. For some more about the fundamentals of FXML, read [Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `start` method needs access to the ComboBox variable declared in the Controller class. It's not sufficient to simply annotate a ComboBox variable with `@FXML` in the Main class.

I solved the problem by adding a `getComboBox` method to the Controller class. This will return the ComboBox instance referred to by the `combo` variable.

```
public ComboBox getComboBox()
{
    return combo;
}
```

In the Main class, use this method to get to the editor underlying the ComboBox:

```
Controller c = loader.getController();
c.getComboBox().getEditor().setOnTyped(c::handleComboKeyPress);
```

Here is the revised Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();

        Controller c = loader.getController();
        c.getComboBox().getEditor().setOnKeyTyped(c::handleComboKeyPress);
    }
```

#### Better Solution

As suggested by @Slaw below, an alternative (and better) solution is to set the keyTyped handler in the Controller. Use an `initialize` method which gets automatically called by the loader if it exists.

```
public void initialize()
{
    combo.getEditor().setOnKeyTyped(this::handleComboKeyPress);
}
```

Here is the entire Controller class (minus the imports):

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private ComboBox combo;

    public void handleComboKeyPress(KeyEvent ke)
    {
        // Do stuff
        System.out.println("key pressed.");
    }

    public void initialize()
    {
        combo.getEditor().setOnKeyTyped(this::handleComboKeyPress);
    }
}
```

Comment: Another option is to set the `KEY_TYPED` handler inside the (no-arg) `initialize()` method of your controller. The `FXMLLoader` will invoke said method after field injection, meaning the `ComboBox` will be available. Doing it this way means you no longer have to call the controller from the `start` method (at least regarding this).

Comment: @Slaw or go one step further and hook the handler directly inside the fxml .. which seems to work (not sure if there might be any unwanted side-effects, though)

Comment: hmm ... re-reading the question: are you sure that scenebuilder doesn't allow references? Never used it, but sounds like a major omission ..

Comment: Scene Builder lets you assign a handler to an event just by selecting the available methods from a pop-up menu. There is an event for onKeyTyped (among many others), but this is for a key typed on the combo box as a whole. The event is not triggered when typing in the text field. I think this is a problem any time you have a UI widget that is a hybrid of two or more other widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option is to hook the event handler directly in the fxml. Not entirely certain if this is safe in all contexts (not a fxml gal, just interested :) - but the `fx:reference` seems to allow access to (arbitrary?) properties of elements.

The following snippet sets the eventHandler for keyTyped to the combo's editor:

```
<ComboBox fx:id="combo" editable="true" />
<fx:reference source="combo.editor" onKeyTyped="#handleTyped" />
```

Which relieves the controller from coding anything except the handler method:

```
@FXML 
private ComboBox<String> combo;

@FXML 
private void handleTyped(KeyEvent ev) {
    System.out.println("ev: " + ev);
}
```

---

*Update*: this seems to not work in fx8 (thanks, Matt for the heads up!) - worksforme in fx11 (didn't test any other)

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know `fx:reference` could be used to do this.

Comment: @Slaw me neither :)

Comment: Your right Im gonna delete that so I don't confuse anyone also Im just curious I am getting a cannot resolve combo.editor any ideas as to why?

Comment: @Matt no, sry .. worksforme with those exact lines in the fxml. Which version do you have? Mine is fx11, maybe anything changed/fixed?

Comment: Ah maybe this is only fx 11 then im still on 8

Comment: @Matt thanks, added a note to include your comment :)